# Cannot select container

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, jpql

I want to create new object with HQL, so I try to issue the following query:

```
    String hql = "SELECT new com.pizzaboy.dto.OrderDTO(o.adress, o.orderDate, dt, r, d)"
            + " FROM Order o JOIN o.user u "
            + " JOIN FETCH o.deliveryType dt"
            + " JOIN FETCH o.restaurant r "
            + " JOIN FETCH o.dishes d"
            //+ " JOIN FETCH d.dishType disht "
            + " WHERE u.id=:id";
```

---

It gives me the following error, as if "o.dishes" weren't List or Set:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.pizzaboy.dto.OrderDTO]. Expected arguments are: com.pizzaboy.pojo.Adress, java.util.Date, com.pizzaboy.pojo.DeliveryType, com.pizzaboy.pojo.Restaurant, com.pizzaboy.pojo.Dish [SELECT new com.pizzaboy.dto.OrderDTO(o.adress, o.orderDate, dt, r, elements(d)) FROM com.pizzaboy.pojo.Order o JOIN o.user u  JOIN FETCH o.deliveryType dt JOIN FETCH o.restaurant r  JOIN FETCH o.dishes d WHERE u.id=:id]
```

However, it is Set, indeed:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", catalog = "PIZZABOY")
public class Order implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private Adress adress;
private DeliveryType deliveryType;
private Payment payment;
private Restaurant restaurant;
private User user;
private Date orderDate;
private Set<Dish> dishes = new HashSet<Dish>(0);

...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Dish> getDishes() {
    return this.dishes;
}

public void setDishes(Set<Dish> dishes) {
    this.dishes = dishes;
}
```

Why do I get this error and how to fix it?

PS OderDTO constructor

```
public OrderDTO(Adress adress, Date orderDate, DeliveryType deliveryType, Restaurant restaurant,
            List<Dish> dishes) {
```

Comment: Please, post the OrderDTO constructor

Comment: @JoeTaras question updated

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, could you use Set (or List) on both objects? Currently you are fetching a Set and trying to use it as a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return collections this way: when you execute HQL/JPQL you are inside an inter-realm between Object-and-Relational worlds, where the result is object-oriented, but the computations happen on table-oriented space.

Why don't make it simple?

```
String hql = "SELECT new com.pizzaboy.dto.OrderDTO(o)"
    + " FROM Order o JOIN o.user u "
    + " JOIN FETCH o.deliveryType dt"
    + " JOIN FETCH o.restaurant r "
    + " JOIN FETCH o.dishes d"
    + " WHERE u.id=:id";
```

and

```
public OrderDTO(Order order) 
{
    this.adress = order.getAddress();
    this.deliveryType = order.getDeliveryType();
    this.restaurant = order.getRestaurant();
    this.dishes = new ArrayList<>(order.getDishes());
}
```

<s>Hiberante will take care to do its work as an ORM, loading related entities/collections of entities and put them in the right place (since you specified `FETCH`, this would *probably* happen with just one SQL query).</s>

It seems it's not possible to eagerly load the collection using an inline `FETCH` and the reason is that there's a technical limitation (maybe it should be considered a bug, similar to the fact you can't join fecth multiple `bags` in a single query).

so you are left with 2 alternatives:

1. remove the `FETCH` from the query and manually initialize the lazy properties:

   ```
   SELECT new com.pizzaboy.dto.OrderDTO(o)
   FROM Order o 
       JOIN o.user u
   WHERE u.id=:id
   ```

   and

   ```
   public OrderDTO(Order order) 
   {
       Hibernate.initialize(order.getAddress());
       this.adress = order.getAddress();

       Hibernate.initialize(order.getDeliveryType());
       this.deliveryType = order.getDeliveryType();

       Hibernate.initialize(order.getRestaurant());
       this.restaurant = order.getRestaurant();

       Hibernate.initialize(order.getDishes());
       this.dishes = new ArrayList<>(order.getDishes());
   }
   ```

   this will expose you to the N+1 problem: can be avoided using `batch-fetch`
2. use a Entity Graph / Fetch Profile:

   ```
   SELECT new com.pizzaboy.dto.OrderDTO(o)
   FROM Order o 
       JOIN o.user u
   WHERE u.id=:id

   EntityGraph<Order> graph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Order.class);
   graph.addAttributeNodes(Order_.deliveryType, Order_.restaurant);
   graph.addSubgraph(Order_.dishes);

   entityManager.createQuery(hql)
       .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph)
       .setParameter("id", userId)
       .getResultList();
   ```

   *Since I've never used entity graphs with custom object selection, this could hit the same bug as using inline join fetch*

However, I don't see much use in returning a `DTO` that's **almost the same thing** as the related `Entity`: just return the entity itself (probably you want it in `DETACHED` state).
*Obviously, this doesn't apply when you have to handle things that are composition of different entities and/or entity properties and/or functional computations like count, sum, a + b, ...*

Comment: It gives me an exception: "query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list."

Comment: "However, I don't see much use in returning a DTO that's almost the same thing as the related Entity: just return the entity itself". I showed the simplified version of my problem. What if DTO is composition of many different objects?